# Counting all the numbers from a text file with re?

Tags: python, regex

I am with the basics of RE, I need open a file with a lot of lines, take only the numbers and shows the average. This is my poor try:

```
import re

try:
    ufile = open(input('What file are you using? '))
except:
    print('File don\'t founded.')
    exit()

lnumbers = []

for line in ufile:
    numbers = re.findall('([0-9.]+) ', line)
    if len(numbers) > 0:
        lnumbers.append(numbers)
```

I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that a given number would never wrap around from one line to the next, then a slight modification of your code should work:

```
for line in ufile:
    numbers = re.findall('[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?', line)
    for number in numbers:
        lnumbers.append(numbers)

if len(lnumbers) > 0:
    print sum(lnumbers) / len(lnumbers)
else:
    print "no numbers were found"
```

Comment: @G_M Fine.  I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following list comprehension to parse all numbers in the file, and then calculate the average based on the new list.

```
lnumbers = [float(number) for line in ufile for number in re.findall('\d+(?:\.\d*)?', line)]
print(sum(lnumbers) / len(lnumbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `map`+`sum`:

```
import re
from statistics import mean

try:
    ufile = open(input('What file are you using? '))
except:
    print('File don\'t founded.')
    exit()

print(mean(sum(list(map(lambda line: list(map(int,re.findall('\d',line))),ufile)),[])))
```